# How does Laravel 4 load deferred provider?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I need to deeply understand laravel. I have to explain everything to my dev team since we are starting to use laravel.

Please correct this if it is wrong: When laravel start, due to increasing performance, it split services provider to 'eager' and 'deferred', then it register all 'eager' provider, but not 'deferred'.

My question:
Each time we use deferred services, e.g:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    //..
);
```

How does laravel load and register that class/services ? I just find this probably related line 70 on `Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository` Class

```
$app->setDeferredServices($manifest['deferred']);
```

But then I stuck. Sorry for bad English, hope you all understands. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wanted to know the answer to this as well, but I decided to look for myself instead.

If you go to `app/storage/meta` there is a `services.json` that lists the `eager` and `deferred` classes. This is so we don't load all classes for every request as we may never need the `Form` class if we are building an API.

The `ProviderRepository` class scans all the providers listed in `app/config/app.php` and instantiates the providers for each of them (These are not the actual libraries).

These providers eg `CacheServiceProvider` in `Illuminate/Cache` have a variable called `defer` that determines whether the library will be eagerly loaded of deferred until needed.

Here is a quote from `ProviderRepository`

> When recompiling the service manifest, we will spin through each of
> the providers and check if it's a deferred provider or not. If so
> we'll add it's provided services to the manifest and note the
> provider.

For the `CacheServiceProvider` this is set to `true`.

So lets say `Validator::make()` is called here is what I have gathered; Each `Facade` such as the `Validator` facade extends the base `Facade` class in `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`.

This has a magic method `__callStatic($method, $args)` which is quite self explanatory, the main point of this method is

```
$instance = static::resolveFacadeInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor());
```

The facade accessor in this case returns a string of the actual class that performs the validation (`Illuminate\Validation\Validator`):

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'validator'; }
```

The main method `resolveFacadeInstance` checks if the returned accessor is an object. If it is it simply returns that back as it is probably a custom Laravel package.

The second part of this method checks if it has already been resolved, if it has then return that. The final part:

```
return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
```

Calls the `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` (which extends the `Illuminate\Container\Container` class)  via the [array access](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface located in the previously mentioned parent class.

So `static::$app[$name]` calls:

```
public function offsetGet($key)
{
    return $this->make($key);
}
```

*This is located in the `Container` class*

Which leads us to the `make()` method in the `Application` class:

```
public function make($abstract, $parameters = array())
{
    if (isset($this->deferredServices[$abstract]))
    {
        $this->loadDeferredProvider($abstract);
    }

    return parent::make($abstract, $parameters);
}
```

I'll let you delve into the `parent::make()` method as this would start getting very lengthy, but as it stands this is where it loads the deferred provider and instantiates it via the `loadDeferredProvider()`

```
public function loadDeferredProviders()
{
    // We will simply spin through each of the deferred providers and register each
    // one and boot them if the application has booted. This should make each of
    // the remaining services available to this application for immediate use.
    foreach (array_unique($this->deferredServices) as $provider)
    {
        $this->register($instance = new $provider($this));

        if ($this->booted) $instance->boot();
    }

    $this->deferredServices = array();
}
```

*The comments in the code block should explain the rest of what is happening.*

From here, the last part of `__callStatic($method, $args)` fires the actual method called `Validator::make()`.

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::resolveFacadeInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor());

    switch (count($args))
    {
        case 0:
            return $instance->$method();

        case 1:
            return $instance->$method($args[0]);

        case 2:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]);

        case 3:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);

        case 4:
            return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);

        default:
            return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
    }
}
```

So the facade calls `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`'s non-static method `validate()`.

**I'm pretty sure this is accurate for 4.0 but please correct me if there any mistakes.**

Comment: mmm, thanks for the answer, I think that's how laravel recompile service.json, not how to load deferred services :( ??, when we call e.g `Cache::put` what are classes/functions being called ?

Comment: @egig See that behemoth of an edit, hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't check `offsetGet($key)` of the container yet, I guess it doesn't use `Make()` method. :D . Thanks A lot.