# How to boot a service provider in laravel 5

Tags: php, package, laravel-5

I am taking my first steps in Laravel 5, specifically with package development. My purpose with this package is to be booted in every single request, always.

So, I started creating the service HelloWorldServiceProvider:

```
<?php
namespace FacebookKiller\Modules\HelloWorld;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HelloWorldServiceProvider extends  ServiceProvider{

    protected $defer = false;

    public function boot(){
        dd('hello world at boot()')
    }

    public function register()
    {
        dd('hello world at register()')
    }
}
```

Actually, this file is this path from root:

```
/Larave/app/Modules/HelloWorld/HelloWorldServiceProvider.php
```

Then, I edit the `config/app.php` file in order to add the service provider

```
'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
// my module
'FacebookKiller\Modules\HelloWorld\HelloWorldServiceProvider'
```

Finally, in order to test if `dd()` is called, I have edited the `routes.php` file like:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return "Making a test request";
});
```

The result is negative. The Service provider is not loaded. According to docs:

> Deferring the loading of such a provider will improve the performance
>   of your application, since it is not loaded from the filesystem on
>   every request.
>   To defer the loading of a provider, set the defer property to true

So, I make the opposite setting `protected $defer` to `false`. But the `dd()` function is not triggered. 
It is important to use Service Provider type because by that way I could load lang, views and config files from it.

Comment: open storage/framework/services.json file, did you see your provider class in this file ? If not, delete this file, laravel will generate it again.

Comment: @MartirosAghajanyan, you fix it! Thank you! Please, create the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete `storage/framework/services.json` file.

Laravel cache all service providers data in this file.
Always look at this file when debugging service providers.

Here is very useful answer about service providers and services.json file

[How does Laravel 4 load deferred provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866067/how-does-laravel-4-load-deferred-provider)

Answer (score 1):

`./artisan clear-compiled`
also does the trick. 
After finding this solution I thought there must be an `artisan` command for this. And bingo, there already is. Taking a look at it's code I saw that besides clearing the compiled classes file it also clears `services.json`.

```
public function fire()
{
    if (file_exists($path = $this->laravel->storagePath().'/framework/compiled.php'))
    {
        @unlink($path);
    }

    if (file_exists($path = $this->laravel->storagePath().'/framework/services.json'))
    {
        @unlink($path);
    }
}
```

In the next bootstrapping of the app `services.json` is recreated.